# Every external device becomes read only after minutes

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have been facing this problem from last week. Cannot paste into or delete files in any usb I plug in after 1 minute or 2. for the first two minutes i am able to paste files into the usb. Cannot figure out what is happening. I am also new to ubuntu, just installed 2 months ago and now this bug is really irritating me.

Comment: If your USB is, for example, `/dev/sdz`, you can see related log messages via `journalctl /dev/sdz`, They might help.

Comment: Which file-system your device uses? Check with `lsblk -f`.